# На KMS не увеличивается счетчик от клонированных windows 7

Tags: windows, активация

Установлена и настроена Windows 7 (без активации). Создан образ системы и расклонирован по некоторому количеству компьютеров.
На KMS счетчик обращений не увеличивается.

Подскажите вариант исправления ситуации и какие дополнительные действия нужно было сделать с образом.

Comment: На серваке `slmgr -dlv` чё пишет?

Comment: @don Rumata
[Вот что пишет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjXNO.png)

Comment: Тачек больше, чем 25? Он до определённого порога лицензии не выдаёт. Только после 25-го уникального обращения. И чё с хостнеймами? Они уникальные?

Comment: @don Rumata, про порог в 25 рабочих станций известно. Компьютеров меньше 25, но гараздо больше того количества сколько показывает счетчик. Имена компьютеров (хостнеймы?), конечно же, уникальные.

Comment: Журналы на серваке и клиенте - молчат? И чё `slmgr` на клиенте говорит, когда ты через него вбиваешь ключ, а потом говоришь `-ato`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может быть решена выполнением команды `slmgr /rearm` и последующей перезагрузкой компьютера.